# Node fs using slash for base directory of the app

Tags: node.js, express, path, fs, absolute-path

Is there a way to use paths starting with a slash (e.g. `/lib`) to access directories absolute to the base dir of my express app?

```
router.get('/lib*', (req, res, next) => {
    var path = req.path;
    console.log(path) // ==> /lib/foo/bar
    fs.readdir(path, (err, names) => {
        if(err)
            next(err);
    });
});
```

This is my filetree:

```
app
├── lib
|    └── some files
├── app.js
└── router.js
```

When accessing the `/lib` route the fs module wants to read `D:\lib` directory.

I'd like to access `D:\(...)\app\lib` though.

Using __dirname wouldn't work if the router was in another directory - I'd like to be flexible

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using `__dirname`.

Replacing

```
var path = req.path;
```

by

```
var filePath = path.join(__dirname, req.path);
```

should give you complete path. You would need to require `path` in the request module.

Comment: Wouldn't work if the router was not in the basedir though

Comment: Yes, you would need to modify path accordingly in that case. For example if router.js file is within a folder say router, your filePath would be `path.join(__dirname, '..', req.path)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var path = require('path');

router.get('/lib*', (req, res, next) => {
        var filepath = req.path;
        console.log(path) // ==> /lib/foo/bar
        fs.readdir(path.resolve(__dirname, filepath), (err, names) => {
            if(err)
                next(err);
        });
    });
```